# Realizing the Jacobian as a quotient, filling in a gap in Rudin's proof.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Suppose $0\in V$ for some open set $V$ in $\mathbb R^k,\ T:V\to \mathbb R^k$ is continuous and differentiable at $x=0.$ Then, $\lim _{r\to 0}\frac{m(T(B(x,r)))}{m(B(x,r))}=\mathcal J_T(0),$ where $\mathcal J_T$ is the Jacobian determinant of $D_T(0)=:A.$

If $A$ is injective, the result follows by a nice application of Brouwer's fixed point theorem. I filled in a gap that appears in the case that $T$ is not one to one and would like to know if my argument is sound. Or if I am missing something trivial, which so often is the case. Rudin's proof goes as follows:

$1).$ Clearly in this case $m(A(\mathbb R^k))=0$ so given $\epsilon>0$, there is an $\eta > 0$ such that $m(E_{\eta }) <\epsilon $ where $E_{\eta }$ is the set of all points in $\mathbb R^k$ whose distance from $A(B(0,1))$ is less than $\eta$.

$2).$ There is also a $\delta>0$ such that $|x|< \delta\Rightarrow |T(x)-Ax|<\eta|x|.$

$2).$ implies that if $r<\delta$ and $y\in T(B(0,r)),$ then $d(y,A(B(O, r))<\eta r$ and from this the claim is that $m(T(B(0,r))) < \epsilon r^k,$ which Rudin states without proof, so it's probably obvious, but it isn't to me, so I wrote it out, using the basic properties of the norm, the $\inf$ and the Lebesgue measure.

$d(y,A(B(0,r))<\eta r\Leftrightarrow  d(y,rA(B(0,1))<\eta r\Leftrightarrow $

$d(\frac{y}{r},A(B(0,1))<\eta\Rightarrow m\left ( \left \{ \frac{y}{r}:y\in T(B(0,r)) \right \} \right )<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow $

$m\left (\frac{1}{r} T(B(0,r))\right )<\epsilon\Rightarrow \frac{1}{r^k} m\left ( T(B(0,r)) \right )<\epsilon \Rightarrow m\left ( T(B(0,r)) \right )<\epsilon r^k.$

From here, it's easy to show that the above limit is $0$, which is the (intuitively expected) result.